# Simulating network and memory in android emulator

Tags: networking, memory

I met problems in simulating of memory and network speed in android emulators. In network speed, I use telnet network speed command to change my emulator's network speed. However, nothing happens and it usually connects with default speed. Android emulator commands also does not effect on it. But I can change battery status by using telnet. What is the case? 
Then I tried to simulate memory of emulator by using shell command ulimit -Sv xxx but nothing effects on the emulator. This command works for windows? I use window 7 and Android Developer Tools v21.1.0 and uses API 15, 16, 17 as emulators.